# Adding checkboxes to an unordered list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What would be the jQuery code to add a checkbox to every `<li>` element in an unordered list and handle their callbacks obtaining the li text or checkbox properties like name/value?

I started with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#SuperTextbox1_Results").children('li').each(function() {
      $(this).prepend('<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="test" />');
   });
});
```

Comment: Please post the code for what you've tried and then I'm sure someone will help you out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// checkbox click event handler
$('input:checkbox.liChk').live('click', function () {
    // access parent li, do whatever you want with it
    console.log($(this).parent('li'));
});    

// append checkboxes to all li tags
$('<input type="checkbox" class="liChk" />').appendTo('li');
```

Comment: Replacing 'li' for $("#your-ul").children('li') will allow adding the checkboxes to a specific unordered list.

Comment: Since .live is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9, should probably use .on instead. (Simply replace .live with .on in example.) http://api.jquery.com/live/